# NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools with version (>= 10.0.19041.8)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-5, azure-pipelines-build-task

In my build pipeline, I have the following step:

[image: Use NuGet]

[image: NuGet restore]

I am getting the following error:

> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools with version (>= 10.0.19041.8)

When I go to the NuGet page for this package: [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools/), I see that it only has one version: `10.0.18362.3-preview`. I am not sure why the NuGet restore step is trying to get a higher version that does not exist. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Note: this is my first Pipeline.

Agent Specification: Windows-2019.

Comment: Can you share also part of the csproj where packages are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools?groupby=Version), you can see only two versions of the package **`Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools`** are listed:

- [10.0.19041.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools/10.0.19041.1)
- [10.0.18362.3-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools/10.0.18362.3-preview)

When open the page of version **`10.0.19041.1`**, you can see the warning message to notify that this package version has been deprecated. But it seems that you can still download and install it.

[image]

I think the other package versions may have been permanently deleted by the owner due to some security vulnerabilities. So you no longer find them.

You can try to open your project using Visual Studio on your local machine, and change to use version **`10.0.18362.3-preview`** in your program.

Comment: This answered my question. I went ahead and removed the reference to the NuGet package because it does not look like it is widely used and we do not appear to be targeting the Windows SDK. Thank you.